# C# cannot convert method to non delegate type

Tags: c#, .net, methods, delegates

I have a class called `Pin`.

```
public class Pin
{
    private string title;

    public Pin() { }

    public setTitle(string title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }
}
```

From another class I add Pins objects in a `List<Pin>` pins and from another I want to iterate the List pins and get the elements. So I have this code.

```
foreach (Pin obj in ClassListPin.pins)
{
     string t = obj.getTitle;
}
```

With this code I cannot retrieve the title. Why?

(Note: `ClassListPin` is just a static class which contains some elements and one of these, is the `List<Pin>` pins)

Comment: Because you need to call it, eg `obj.getTitle()`

Comment: Have you tried searching the googles? This is a fairly common beginner's error.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but properties were introduced to oppose writing setters and getters.  For more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: I admit that it was a silly error...

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You need to add parentheses after a method call, else the compiler will think you're talking about the method itself (a delegate type), whereas you're actually talking about the return value of that method.

```
string t = obj.getTitle();
```

---

**Extra Non-Essential Information**

Also, have a look at properties. That way you could use title as if it were a variable, while, internally, it works like a function. That way you don't have to write the functions `getTitle()` and `setTitle(string value)`, but you could do it like this:

```
public string Title // Note: public fields, methods and properties use PascalCasing
{
    get // This replaces your getTitle method
    {
        return _title; // Where _title is a field somewhere
    }
    set // And this replaces your setTitle method
    {
        _title = value; // value behaves like a method parameter
    }
}
```

Or you could use auto-implemented properties, which would use this by default:

```
public string Title { get; set; }
```

And you wouldn't have to create your own backing field (`_title`), the compiler would create it itself.

Also, you can change access levels for property accessors (getters and setters):

```
public string Title { get; private set; }
```

You use properties as if they were fields, i.e.:

```
this.Title = "Example";
string local = this.Title;
```

Comment: oh my god... it was a childish mistake!

Answer (score 8):

`getTitle` is a function, so you need to put `()` after it.

```
string t = obj.getTitle();
```

Answer (score 8):

As @Antonijn stated, you need to **execute** getTitle method, by adding parentheses:

```
 string t = obj.getTitle();
```

But I want to add, that you are doing Java programming in C#. There is concept of [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) (pair of get and set methods), which should be used in such cases:

```
public class Pin
{
    private string _title;

    // you don't need to define empty constructor
    // public Pin() { }

    public string Title 
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { _title = value; }
    }  
}
```

And even more, in this case you can ask compiler not only for get and set methods generation, but also for back storage generation, via [auto-impelemented property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) usage:

```
public class Pin
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

And now you don't need to **execute** method, because properties used like fields:

```
foreach (Pin obj in ClassListPin.pins)
{
     string t = obj.Title;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned you need to use `obj.getTile()`

But, in this case I think you are looking to use a [Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).

```
public class Pin
{
    private string title;

    public Pin() { }

    public setTitle(string title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String Title
    {
        get { return title; }
    }
}
```

This will allow you to use

```
foreach (Pin obj in ClassListPin.pins)
{
     string t = obj.Title;
}
```

Comment: It should be `Title` then, not `getTitle`.

Answer (score 6):

You can simplify your class code to this below  and it will work as is but if you want to make your example work, add parenthesis at the end :  string x = getTitle();

```
public class Pin
{
   public string Title { get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `getTitle` is not a `string`, it returns a reference or `delegate` to a method (if you like), if you don't explicitly *call* the method.

Call your method this way:

```
string t= obj.getTitle() ; //obj.getTitle()  says return the title string object
```

However, this would work:

```
Func<string> method = obj.getTitle; // this compiles to a delegate and points to the method

string s = method();//call the delegate or using this syntax `method.Invoke();`
```

Answer (score 3):

To execute a method you need to add parentheses, even if the method does not take arguments.

So it should be:

```
string t = obj.getTitle();
```